# Error al compilar al tratar de utilizar firestore de firebase

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, firebase, react-redux

estoy realizando un proyecto de E-commerce y al tratar de usar la DB firestore de firebase me sale un error al compilar mi aplicación: Attempted import error: 'FetchXmlHttpFactory' is not exported from '@firebase/webchannel-wrapper' (imported as 'v')
Ya instale @firebase/webchannel-wrapper y lo importe a mi "Home" y aún continua saliendo el error.
Les agradecería si me pudieran ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: Justo actualicé firebase y me salió ese error ahora con la versión 8.6.4

Comment: Parece ya estar resuelto: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4977#issuecomment-854857934 Sólo hay que esperar a que saquen la versión nueva.

Comment: Gracias nelson6e65